# how can i find roots of $4{x^3}+24{x^2}+74{x}+50 $?

Tags: numerical-methods

There is one root between 0 and -1. than how can i find that root by hit and trial method. or any other method that can be used.

Comment: Bisection, Newton's method.

Comment: Since this is a cubic polynomial, you can actually solve for the roots [explicitly](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula), if you'd like.

Comment: I want easy and fast method

Comment: Who doesn't? ${}{}$

Comment: The easiest and fastest method is surely to [ask a mathematical oracle](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%E2%88%97x^3%2B24%E2%88%97x^2%2B74%E2%88%97x%2B50).

Comment: Try `roots([4 24 74 50])` in Octave/Matlab.

Comment: It would be slightly easier if the constant factor 2 were divided out.  The Rational Root test is worth trying generally, though here it shows only that no rational number is a root. Once you have bracketed a real root between -1 and 0, bisection for a couple of iterations followed by four Newton iterations (which are especially easy for polynomials a la Horner's method) is apt to give double precision accuracy.

Comment: "I want easy and fast method": do you mean by hand or with a calculator ? Or do you mean easy to program ? How accurate do you want it ? ...

Comment: Make a sketch of the function by plotting it. Take the Newton- Raphson first iterate sufficiently  close to to cutting point of curve to the x-axis in your chosen domain.

Answer (score 4):

There are [closed formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function) for the third degree equation.

The way that you know how to solve the quadratic equation exactly with $\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, there are similar expressions for the cubic and quartic case, after the work of Tartaglia, Cardano and others in the $XVI^{th}$ Century.

They are a little complicated and heavily involve complex numbers, but they can outperform the iterative methods.

After decades of unfruitful searches for the solution of higher degree equations, Galois and Abel settled the case: there are no such formulas in the general case.

Comment: Can you elaborate it.

Comment: Hem, click the link.

Comment: @hardmath: I have commented a little, but in this particular case I think the link is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the Newton_Raphson Method
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{y_n}{y'_n}$$

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{4x^3_n+24x^2_n+74x_n+50}{12x^2_n+48x_n+74}=\frac{8x^3_n+24x^2_n-50}{12x^2_n+48x_n+74}$$

then use initial value $x_0=-0.5$

Answer (score 2):

You may like the method of bisection due to its simplicity.We have f(0) = 50,
f(-1) = -4.The root is in this interval.Calculate f(-.5).If that is negative,
then the root is between -.5 and 0.If f(-.5) is positive,then the root is between -1 and -.5.At each step,you bisect the interval,and compute the function
at the mid-point.You will always know that the root is between 2 values.Keep
doing this until you have achieved your desired degree of accuracy. Edwin Gray

Answer (score 2):

The values $f(0)=50$ and $f(-1)=-4$ tell us that the root is found more close to $-1$. Substitute $x=-1+y$,
$$
f(-1+y)=4(-1+3y-3y^2+y^3)+24(1-2y+y^2) +74(-1+y) +50\\
=4y^3+12y^2+38y-4
$$
From there we get, following in the footsteps of Newton, that a solution is to be found close to $y=4/38=2/19\approx 0.1$. Inserting $y=0.1$ into the fixed point equation obtained from isolating the dominant linear term gives
$$
y=\frac{4-12y^2-4y^3}{38}=\frac{3.876}{38}=0.102
$$
Thus the solution can be found close to $x=-1+0.102=-0.898$.

Answer (score 0):

Try ${\left( \frac{\sqrt{12197}}{4\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\frac{17}{4}\right) }^{\frac{1}{3}}−\frac{13}{6\,{\left( \frac{\sqrt{12197}}{4\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\frac{17}{4}\right) }^{\frac{1}{3}}}−2 $

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

we have only one real root
$$-2+\frac{\sqrt[3]{153+\sqrt{36591}}}{6^{2/3}}-\frac{13}{\sqrt[3]{6
   \left(153+\sqrt{36591}\right)}}$$

Comment: how you came to this expression